# How to tell how many affixes an item can have?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've read on diablo wiki that a rare item can have between 2-6 affixes with a maximum amount of each 3 suffixes and prefixes. I know from experience that a magic item can have 1-2 affixes and pools from all rare affixes, but can have it's own unique affixes, that can never happen on a rare. My goal is to see what items are worth picking up and I need to know how many affixes it can get. Does it depend on characterlevel or itemlevel or something else? Where can I read up on this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: White/grey items can have affixes as well like necro wands, sorc staffs, druid helms, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item suffix and prefix ALWAYS depend on the item level, never the character level. To find out what the item level table is, you need to look at the monster level to find out what the item pool is.

The link below is where you can read up on everything and get a little nostalgia from the early internet days.

[The list of suffix and prefix are located here](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/magic/suf.shtml)

The number of affixes on an item is completely random. Like you said, magic items can have 0-1 prefix and 0-1 suffix on them. Rare items can have 1-3 prefix and 1-3 suffix. The only other rare item that does NOT pertain to this rule are rare jewels, which are limited to 4 total affixes (2 and 2 respectively) as of patch 1.09. You'll probably be on 1.14d if you've updated at all in the last decade, but I thought I'd mention this anyway.

Comment: My question is not what kind of suffixes can spawn on an item. I know that it depends on the ItemLevel and the AffixLevel (that depends on ItemLevel and CLevel). My question is how many affixes can spawn on a item. https://diablo.gamepedia.com/Rare_Items_(Diablo_II): this link just says that an item can have 2-6 affixes. Does that mean that rare chain gloves with a high enough ilevel can have 6 affixes as well as rare circlets or rings? And on what does it depend? What item level is the first to be able to give me 6 affixes on rare? Or is it just random and I'm lucky if my item got 6 affixes?

Comment: I know that in crafting items you can guarantee that the item will have the maximum number of affixes, if the item level is high enough. But I think its different with rares.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Oh! I'll update my answer. (hint: it's totally random)

Comment: Hmm, ok so you could find a rare with 6 affixes in normal Cold Plains? I think I've seen rares like that. Ofc the stats are low cause the affixes are low, but the quantity might be 6.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Correct! I added the number of suffix and prefix for magic and rares to my answer and I also gave the exception.